# ActivityNotFoundException when launching intent from preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, action, preferences

test.class type is right? How to? What should I do?

```
<Preference 
    android:key="test" 
    android:title="test" 
    android:summary="test"> 
   <intent android:action="test.class" >  <=== **ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2384): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent** 
    </intent>  
</Preference>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 13):

I believe the question is asking how to launch an activity from a PreferenceScreen. This can be achieved using the following definition in your XML:

```
<Preference
  android:title="Tap me"
  android:summary="Tap to start activity">
  <intent
     android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
     android:targetPackage="com.example"
     android:targetClass="com.example.MyActivityClass" />
</Preference>
```

Finally, **make sure the Activity is defined in your manifest**.

Comment: Wanted to comment on this. 

Basically the **targetClass** is the _full package + class_, whereas the **targetPackage** is your applications package as specified in the manifest, for example:

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ekawas.blogspot.com" ...`

**targetPackage** would then be: **targetPackage="ekawas.blogspot.com"**

Comment: how to handle if target class is not found?